# PowerShell function output

Tags: powershell

I have a PowerShell script that calls a function and sets the results of the function to a variable. Within the function, I am using the `$variable | ft` to display the contents of a variable in a table and asking the user to select a number that corresponds to the row in the table they want to act on. I am then returning this variable to the object that called the function:

```
function getusers{
    $users = @()
    $i = 0
    do {
        $user = ""| select Row, Username, Firstname, lastname
        $user.row = $i
        $user.username ="user$i"
        $user.Firstname = "fname$i"
        $user.lastname = "lname$i"
        $users += $user
        $i += 1
    }while ($i -le 5)

    # Actual logic to build the contents of the $users variable here.
    $users | ft -AutoSize
    $selection = Read-Host "Select number for appropriate user"

    # Logic to determine if user selection is a valid number based on the number of rows in the variable.
    $user = $users[$selection]
    $user
}
$selecteduser = getusers
```

When calling the function and storing the results in a variable the `$users | ft` does not display in my console. If I just call the function without storing the results in a variable, the console displays the results of `$users | ft`.

Comment: User `Out-Gridview` with the `-passthru` parameter instead of `Format-Table`

Comment: It's unclear what this code is supposed to achieve. Create 5 "user" objects and then only return one of them? Why create the 4 others then? Also the *"logic to determine if user selection is a valid number"* does nothing even close to that. Explain what this code is for.

Comment: What about `return $user` as the last command in the function?

Comment: @LotPings There is no need to use `return` statements in PowerShell. Any value that is not assigned to a variable is returned.

Comment: [Get-Help about_return](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_return?view=powershell-6) tells me it's not neccessary - but not useless ;-)

Comment: @Tomalak I am building the content of the $users variable from AD and SQL tables and consolidating the results into the variable.  The logic for this operation is about 30 lines and I omitted it for brevity.  I added the loop so that the variable has values in the correct format for anyone to test with.

Comment: @Tomalak The results could return a various number of users depending on the criteria used to build the $users variable.  I am using logic after a user has made a selection to verify that the selection is a number, and that number falls in the range of 0 – to the number of records in the $users variable so that when referencing the selection in the array, I get a valid result.

Comment: @EBGreen the out-gridview -passthrou option pops up a windows screen that shows the results, but the script is halted until the screen is closed.  I want it to display in the powershell console.

Comment: If you assign the output of Out-Gridview to a variable then the user can select a line and click ok them the values in that row will be assigned to the variable.

Comment: @EBGreen an interesting solution, but i want to keep everything in a console screen.  don't want to use the mouse to make the selection

Comment: The question remains the same. If you have N records, and the user is to select 1 one of them, why are you fetch all of them first and then throw N-1 away? That's useless. Let the user enter a number and fetch 1 record according to that.

Comment: In that case you will need to use Write-Host to display the information rather than Format-Table.

Comment: @EBGreen write-host does not disply the results of the variable in table format which is what i need.

Comment: @Tomalak i am building a script that walks the users through a series of prompts to get information for users based on 6 different classifications.  Once all the classifications are made, a list of users is displayed that meets the classifications.  The user of the script than selects which user they want the script to run on.  I feel like your getting hung up on my methodology more so that my actual issue which is how do i display the contents of a variable using the | FT output within a function when the results of the function are stored in a variable that calls the function

Comment: So you have three choices. You can use Out-Gridview. You can use Write-Host to create your own table. Or you can move the code out of a function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like your question is the following:

How can you display the output of [Format-Table](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849892.aspx) in the console when you are calling Format-Table inside of a function where the final output of the function is being assigned to a variable?

From the comments it is clear that you do not want to significantly alter your code, and that you do not want to use something like Out-GridView.

In order to achieve this with the smallest change possible you can change your code:

```
$users | ft
```

to the following:

```
$users | ft | Out-Host
```

This will print the results of Format-Table to the console, and the value at the end of the function

```
$user
```

will be assigned to the variable.

It was tested on Windows 7, PowerShell version 4, in both the ISE and running as a script.

Comment: Using `Out-Host` as suggested in this answer seems like a reasonable solution, but I'm not sure the OP understands why this is happening.   There's almost certainly other answers that might help him understand how multiple outputs work in PowerShell, linking to one might improve the answer